# ValueError to {key:value for i in l for key, value in i.split(':')}

Tags: python

Suppose a list:

```
l=['The basics: URLconfs | View functions | Shortcuts | Decorators',
 'Reference: Built-in Views | Request/response objects | TemplateResponse objects',
 'File uploads: Overview | File objects | Storage API | Managing files | Custom storage',
 'Class-based views: Overview | Built-in display views | Built-in editing views | Using mixins | API reference | Flattened index',
 'Advanced: Generating CSV | Generating PDF',
 'Middleware: Overview | Built-in middleware classes']
```

I would like to convert it to a dict

```
In [27]: {i.split(':')[0]: i.split(':')[1] for i in l}
Out[27]:
{'Advanced': ' Generating CSV | Generating PDF',
 'Class-based views': ' Overview | Built-in display views | Built-in editing views | Using mixins | API reference | Flattened index',
 'File uploads': ' Overview | File objects | Storage API | Managing files | Custom storage',
 'Middleware': ' Overview | Built-in middleware classes',
 'Reference': ' Built-in Views | Request/response objects | TemplateResponse objects',
 'The basics': ' URLconfs | View functions | Shortcuts | Decorators'}
```

It's verbose that repeated `i.split(':')` occurs, so I tried

```
{key:value for i in l for key, value in i.split(':')}
```

It reports error otherwise

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

How to accomplish it in a succinct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict(item.split(':') for item in l)
```